# Compute variance on GroupedData

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to compute the variance on a GroupedData object in PySpark 2. Looking at http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData, I don't see any built-in functions for computing variance.

Is there an efficient way to compute the variance on a GroupedData object in PySpark2?

Here is example code of how I would compute the mean, min, and max on a GroupedData object, but I'm not sure how to compute the variance:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

columns = ['a', 'b']
vals = [('x', 3), ('x', 5), ('y', 1), ('y', 8), ('y', 4), ('z', 5), ('z', 7), ('z', 4), ('z', 9)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)

df.groupBy('a').agg(avg('b'), min('b'), max('b')).show()
```

The dataframe `df` looks like:

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  x|  3|
|  x|  5|
|  y|  1|
|  y|  8|
|  y|  4|
|  z|  5|
|  z|  7|
|  z|  4|
|  z|  9|
+---+---+
```

I would like to create a new dataframe similar to the following, showing the variance:

```
+---+--------+
|  a|   b_var|
+---+--------+
|  x|  1.0000|
|  y|  8.2222|
|  z|  3.6875|
+---+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in functions are [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.var_pop); There are two methods `var_pop` and `var_samp` in the `pyspark.sql.functions` module calculating population variance and sample variance respectively, what you need is the *var_pop* function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

(df.groupBy("a").agg(
    F.round(F.var_pop("b"), 2).alias("var_pop_b"), 
    F.round(F.var_samp("b"), 2).alias("var_samp_b")
)).show()
+---+---------+----------+
|  a|var_pop_b|var_samp_b|
+---+---------+----------+
|  x|      1.0|       2.0|
|  z|     3.69|      4.92|
|  y|     8.22|     12.33|
+---+---------+----------+
```